# Please help me with finding if I need to add a resistor to my circuit

Tags: resistors, basic

I want to connect 3 4V LED strips in series to a 12V, 1A supply. Each strip requires 250mA current to operate. This makes a total of 750mA required current for all 3 strips. My concern is how should I deal with the remaining 250mA?

Should I add a resistor? How much ohm resistor should I add?
It will be so nice of the responder if he/she shows me how to do the math to such.

Comment: Connecting in series, current will still be 250mA.

Comment: Oh! Ok! Thank you! Then how much ohms the resistor will be to reduce 1A to 250mA

Comment: Does a battery need a resistor when it is supplying zero pico amps to "air" when sat on a shelf? Will your power supply?

Comment: So, you mean I will not be requiring to connect any resistor? Right?

Comment: Not so easy to say - a data sheet of the LED strip is ideally required. Please provide a technical link to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to add to what people have already said. But I have attached a rough circuit. altering R2 will help you control how much current should flow thought the LED loop. Also, this circuit doesn't take into account the forward bias Voltage(found on datasheet). You need to compensate for that with your source voltage.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In series, voltages add.  Current does not.

Each strip requires 4V at 250mA.  Your power supply must therefore deliver 12V at 250mA to your LED strips.

Whether the three strips will light that is a different problem.

LEDs require that the voltage supplied be at or above the forward voltage of the LED.  Below that, they do not light.  They are not dim, they do not flicker.  They do not light up.

Above the forward voltage, an LED acts very much like a short circuit.  You must limit the current when dealing with LEDs.

The typical way to do this is to subtract the LED forward voltage (\$V_f\$) from the supply voltage (\$V_S\$ then divide by the desired current (\$I\$) to get the required value for a series resistor (\$R\$.)

$$R = \frac{V_S - V_f}{I}$$

You'll see one small problem there.  The equation doesn't give you reasonable values for values where \$V_f >=V_S\$.

It's worse than that even.

The forward voltage of LEDs varies with temperature and current.  It can be a little higher or a little lower than the stated forward voltage.  One day it might be 12V, another day it might be 12.1V - or on another day it might be 11.9V.

The safest thing to do is to use a supply voltage at least a couple volts higher than the forward voltage, then use the formula above.

---

Now to make it even messier.

4V is not a normal LED forward voltage.  Your LED strips have either a series resistor or some kind of current regulator built in.

That will mess up any calculation you try to do that doesn't account for what's really in the LED.

If they have a series resistor or other current limiting built in, then they may operate just fine with 3 in series on 12V.

You didn't link to a datasheet for the strips, so we can't help you figure it out.